# SpringData/Hibernate: Sort enum by it's field

Tags: java, hibernate, sorting, enums, spring-data

I have small problem with sorting enums by custom rule with springdata/hibernate.

A have an enum called let's say: DeviceState, which has its own priority field.

```
public enum DeviceState {
    ON(4), OFF(3), UPDATE(2), CRITICAL(0), WARNING(1);
    private final int priority;

    private DeviceState(int priority) {
        this.priority = priority;
    }

    public int getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }
}
```

The enum is used by DeviceEntity:

```
@Entity
public class Device implements Serializable {

    // .... other fields

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private DeviceState state;

    // ....
}
```

I use SpringData/Repository to get entities from database, I have used findAll(specification, pageable) method from org.springframework.data.repository.Respository class.

```
Page<Device> pagedDevices = deviceRepository.findAll(DeviceSpecifications.findByFilter(filter), pageable);
```

And if my request cointains sort=state,asc it will return the Devices sorted by state - alphabetically, but I would like to use priority field as sort criteria instead.

What have i tried:
change @Enumerated(STRING) to @Enumerated(ORIDINAL) - but this cannot happen  this is production working system with existing data, there are several devices which are using by external system and my project needs String values.

[Control sort order of Hibernate EnumType.STRING properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605655/control-sort-order-of-hibernate-enumtype-string-properties) but i cannot add any new column since I already have production data and all enum values are persisted as String.

I also have tried some "workarounds" with wrapping Page result - but these are just workarounds not pure solutions :)

Any clue, help? idea?
Please keep in mind that this is production working system and I cannot do any "fireworks".

Answer (score 1):

```
order by case 
  when state = 'CRITICAL' then 0
  when state = 'WARNING' then 1
  when state = 'UPDATE' then 2
  when state = 'OFF' then 3
  when state = 'ON' then 4
  end
```

Comment: I wanted to use that solution before but I use spring data / repository findAll(specification, pageable) method and the only thing which I can customize is specification (query filters).
Pageable context (first result, max results, size, SORT etc) is maintained by spring-data - so I can't modify that.
So this solution might be OK - but not in my case.
Thanks anyway ;)

ps: i was also trying to play with @Formula annotation from javax.persistance. Failed :(

Comment: Adding to @siepyta comment, you actually can move all sorting logics to query using criteria builder. Had this on project before switching to spring data. Looks really ugly...