# Mapping an enum named EMPLOYEE to a VARCHAR discriminator value 'M'

Tags: java, jpa, enums, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

This is basically a follow-up question or repost as question [How to use enums with JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352586/how-to-use-enums-with-jpa) seems to have been solved in a proprietary way. This is the 2012 **JPA** question of basically the same, here using **EclipseLink 2.3.2**.

The question is how to map a Java enum to a DB string with different names. There is a DB column with the VARCHAR values `'M'`, `'C'`, `'N'`, and `'F'`. They are cryptic and mix English and German. To improve the business layer I want to map a Java enum to the above DB strings:

```
public enum TradingSector
{
    EMPLOYEE( "M" ), // Mitarbeiter
    CUSTOMER( "C" ),
    NOSTRO( "N" ),
    FUND( "F" );

// this works:
//    M( "M" ),
//    C( "C" ),
//    N( "N" ),
//    F( "F" );

    private final String ch;

    private TradingSector( String ch )
    {
        this.ch = ch;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return this.ch;
    }
}
```

Here's the entity:

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "TRADES" )
@Inheritance( strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE )
@DiscriminatorColumn( name = "NOSTRO_FLAG", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, length = 1 )
public class Trade implements Serializable
{
    @Enumerated( EnumType.STRING )
    @Column( name = "NOSTRO_FLAG", insertable = false, updatable = false )
    private TradingSector discriminator;

    ...
}
```

This is kind of special, **mapping an enum to what is already the inheritance discriminator**. This however should work, as the enums named like the DB strings show.

The `TRADES` table is the most monolithic one in the whole context right now and it's more than desirable to split the entity up into sub classes.

I had expected simply overriding `toString` to work from what I read, but this results in:

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-116] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: No conversion value provided for the value [M] in field [TRADES.TRADING_SECTOR].
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectToFieldMapping[discriminator-->TRADES.TRADING_SECTOR]
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(com.company.project.model.Trade --> [DatabaseTable(TRADES)])
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException.noFieldValueConversionToAttributeValueProvided(DescriptorException.java:1052)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.converters.ObjectTypeConverter.convertDataValueToObjectValue(ObjectTypeConverter.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.converters.EnumTypeConverter.convertDataValueToObjectValue(EnumTypeConverter.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.foundation.AbstractDirectMapping.getAttributeValue(AbstractDirectMapping.java:699)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.foundation.AbstractDirectMapping.valueFromRow(AbstractDirectMapping.java:1299)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DatabaseMapping.readFromRowIntoObject(DatabaseMapping.java:1326)
```

Here's what the EclipseLink error docs at http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink_Exception_Error_Reference_%28ELUG%29 say:

```
 ECLIPSELINK-00116: No conversion value provided for the value [{0}] in field [{1}].
    Cause: The attribute conversion value for the fieldValue was not given in the object type mapping. 
    Action: Verify the field value, and provide a corresponding attribute value in the mapping.
```

Ah, yes. :-/

**Q**: 
What's the *non-proprietary* (JPA 2) way to solve this (if that's possible at all, without going too far into the hacking trenches)?

PS: It's not possible to change the DB values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Damn, I missed Pascal Thivent's **great** answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2751896/396732

Here's the final solution:

Enum:

```
public enum TradingSector
{
    EMPLOYEE( "M" ),
    CUSTOMER( "C" ),
    NOSTRO( "N" ),
    FUND( "F" );

    private final String ch;

    private TradingSector( String ch )
    {
        this.ch = ch;
    }

    public String getCharacter()
    {
        return this.ch;
    }

    public static TradingSector translate( String ch )
    {
        for ( TradingSector ts : TradingSector.values() )
        {
            if ( ch.equals( ts.getCharacter() ) )
            {
                return ts;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "TRADES" )
@Inheritance( strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE )
@DiscriminatorColumn( name = "NOSTRO_FLAG", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, length = 1 )
public abstract class Trade implements Serializable
{
    @Column( name = "NOSTRO_FLAG", insertable = false, updatable = false )
    protected String discriminator;

    @Id
    @Column( name = "TRADE_ID" )
    protected Long id;

    ...

    protected Trade()
    {
    }

    public String getDiscriminator()
    {
        return this.discriminator;
    }

    public TradingSector getTradingSector()
    {
        return TradingSector.translate( this.discriminator );
    }

    ...
}
```

Still useful to some degree.