# Load properties from Database to Enums

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, properties, enums

I have many tables with data which are used as properties in my application. These data change very infrequently, they are like constants. In my application I have some classes enum which represent those tables, this is one of them:

```
public enum MyEnum {
  ENUM_ONE {
    public String getCode() {
      return "1";
    }
  },
  ENUM_TWO {
    public String getCode() {
      return "2";
    }
  };

  private static final String tableName = "MYENUMTABLE";

  public abstract String getCode();

  public String getTableName() {
    return tableName;
  }
}
```

The thing is that, as you can see in the code above, this is hardcode (isn't it?), so I wonder if it possible to create some code to load these properties when the application starts-up.

The application is built with Java, Hibernate, Spring framework, Oracle 11.2.0.3 ... maybe it exists something with any of these tools.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352586/how-to-use-enums-with-jpa)?

Comment: @BuhakeSindi Sorry, I don't see the possible duplicate, in that post the enum is hard-coded too, isn't it? I would like it to be loaded from databse, and these enums could have a lots of entries and can be used in many different classes. Is it possible?

Comment: Enums are constants so and should be treated as a constant. If you want those entries to be loaded in memory and be reused by various classes, you can have them cached in a cache and call the values from the cache.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, I would have created the enum as follows (see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978654/java-string-enum/3978690#3978690)):

```
public enum MyEnum {
    ENUM_ONE("1"),
    ENUM_TWO("2")
    ;
    private final String code;

    private MyEnum(final String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    //Not nearly necessary since the toString() method returns the same value.
    public String getCode() {
      return code;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return code;
    }
 };
```

Then, supposing you're using MySQL database & JPA as your question doesn't specify what RDBMS you're using and ORM API per say, the [`@Column`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Column.html) annotation contains the [`columnDefinition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Column.html#columnDefinition()) property where you can define your `ENUM` DDL definition,

E.g.,

```
@Column(name="CODE_ENUM", table="MYENUMTABLE", columnDefinition="ENUM(2) NOT NULL") //table is OPTIONAL
private MyEnum codeEnum;

//Generate getters and setters.
```

This is an example that uses JPA so your Hibernate must support JPA.

---

For Oracle, you can use `@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)` instead of using `columnDefinition` for your requirement.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Still, which Oracle version? You **have to be very** specific.

Comment: I've just updated the post with the version of Oracle.